# How to allow Domain in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip

I am trying to only allow access to my raspberry pi from my website which is hosted from a provider. I found the following in the internet:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.0/24
allow from ..external ip to pi..
allow from hurl.it
```

When I want for example hurl.it to get access to my pi, the pi blocks anyway. Do I make mistake handling with domains in htaccess?

Thanks for every response.

UPDATE:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
allow from localhost
allow from 192.168.1
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from ..external ip to pi..
Satisfy Any
```

I tried this one for the basic authorization.

Comment: Do you mean you want your website server to access the Pi, or visitors to your website to access it via the website? Please explain your setup in more detail.

Comment: Yes. It works as an base station for interacting with smart home things, which are only available in the LAN. The pi is only available for my account which is located by the provider. But this is not part of the apache configuration.

Comment: Ok thanks, I added an answer for you.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at using [Apache basic auth](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth) instead of this method you are looking at. Basic auth is simple to set up, and then you just access your Pi as:

```
http://user:password@123.123.123.123/
```

Replacing 123.123.123.123 with you external IP at home.

Also look at setting up HTTPS so communication is encrypted.

**Update**

You don't need the allow directives when using basic auth. Just `order allow,deny` and `allow from all`. The basic auth will stop anyone who is not authenticated. So just use:

```
order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: I already tried it also with the basic auth. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It always display, that the authorization failed (401).

Comment: Then something was wrong with your setup, that's all. You could post your setup for help with that. Test it from within your home network on your internal IP.

Comment: Okay, thank you. now it works on hurl.it. I must look if there is an alternative on my website in PHP for file_get_contents().

Comment: But in general, how can I add an domain or is this impossible?

Comment: You need to use the domain, or end part of it, that the IP address connecting to the server resolves to, and that name needs to resolve to that IP too.

Comment: So can I also use the ip from the provider or do I misunderstood that?

Comment: You can use whatever IP the web server connects to your Pi as, which may not be the same as the IP address of your site